# What for do we need ignite.sh script?

Tags: java, ignite

I'm new to ignite and trying to run my simple multi-node computation example. I wrote the following simple application:

```
try(Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("example-cache.xml")){
       IgniteCompute asyncCompute = ignite.compute().withAsync();
       for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
           int[] a = new int[1];
           a[0] = i;
           asyncCompute.call(() -> {
               out.println(a[0]);
               return a[0];
           });
       }
 }
```

First I ran 3 server nodes with `ignite.sh` that is supplied with the binary ignite distribution. Each in a different JVM instance.

Then I build this application and run it with the same xml-spring config as the 3 server nodes before.

But actually I got the following exception:

```
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: com.test.App
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.unmarshal(IgniteUtils.java:9826)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.initialize(GridJobWorker.java:432)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.processJobExecuteRequest(GridJobProcessor.java:1108)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor$JobExecutionListener.onMessage(GridJobProcessor.java:1894)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1222)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:850)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$2100(GridIoManager.java:108)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$7.run(GridIoManager.java:790)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryInvalidTypeException: com.test.App
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:692)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadClass(BinaryUtils.java:1486)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadClass(BinaryUtils.java:1424)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.readClass(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:370)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.readFixedType(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:828)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.read(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:639)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.read(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:833)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1498)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1450)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadObject(BinaryUtils.java:1640)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.readObject(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1124)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$C2V2.readBinary(GridClosureProcessor.java:2073)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.read(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:823)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1498)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1450)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.GridBinaryMarshaller.deserialize(GridBinaryMarshaller.java:298)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryMarshaller.unmarshal0(BinaryMarshaller.java:99)
        at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:82)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.unmarshal(IgniteUtils.java:9820)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.App
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.forName(IgniteUtils.java:8459)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextAdapter.getClass(MarshallerContextAdapter.java:185)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:683)
```

This exception is perfectly clear. But what do we need the `ignite.sh` script for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either add you App class in classpath for all ignite nodes or
turn on peer-class-loading[1].

[1] https://apacheignite.readme.io/v1.9/docs/zero-deployment#peer-class-loading

Answer (score 1):

You should add your JAR file to the lib/ folder under the Apache Ignite installation folder. Then you can start ignite.sh and all your classes will be automatically loaded.

Alternatively, you can try enabling peer-class-loading as suggested above, and Ignite will load the classes automatically.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. But what is the recommended way?

Comment: Depends on your requirements. In development, I would definitely recommend to turn on the peer class loading, as it will save you a lot of time on deployment. If you run into issues with it, then switch to the JAR deployment.